# Natbib - setcitestyle

Tags: natbib

I am using natbib and need the following reference output:

> (Badie 2010: 1-2)

Therefore, I am using the setcitestyle command.

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
```

gives me the following output:

> (Badie, 2010: 1-2)

When using

```
\setcitestyle{aysep{}}
```

I get

> (Badie 2010, 1-2)

But combining both, is not possible

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={: },aysep{}}
```

gives me

> (Badie, 2010: 1-2)

Can you tell me why? What have I made wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: You need to use `aysep={}` instead of `aysep{}`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{badie2010,
 author={Badie, John},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

\begin{document}
\citep[1--2]{badie2010}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]